# Correct implementation of refresh button

Tags: flutter

It may seems a simple question (and maybe it is) but I'm new to Flutter and I don't find the correct way to implement this feature.

I have a Stateful Widget inside a `CupertinoPageScaffold`.
The scaffold is inside a `CupertinoNavigationBar` that has a `CupertinoButton` "Refresh" button.

The widget has the `FutureBuilder` to asynchronously build the content.

By pushing this button I want to refresh the state of the widget inside the scaffold.

The button has of course the `onPressed()` closure, but **I don't understand how the button can interact with the state of the Widget** (indeed, the `setState()` should only be called inside the widget's state itself).

```
+---------------------------+
|  Refresh                  |
|  Button+-----------------------------+
+---------------------------+          |
|                           |          |
|  +--Stateful Widget+---+  |          |
|  |                     |  |          |
|  | +----------------+  |  |          |
|  | |                |  |  |          |
|  | |                |  |  |          |
|  | |                |  |  |          |
|  | |    State       |  |  |          |
|  | |     &          |  |  |          |
|  | |    Future    <------------------+
|  | |    Builder     |  |  |
|  | |                |  |  |
|  | |                |  |  |
|  | |                |  |  |
|  | +----------------+  |  |
|  |                     |  |
|  +---------------------+  |
|                           |
+---------------------------+
```

How is the correct way to implement this refresh button?

**EDIT**

Currently this is what I have:

```dart
class PostListScaffold extends StatelessWidget {

  final CategoryMetadata category;

  PostListScaffold({this.category});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/logo.png")),
        heroTag: "post_list",
        transitionBetweenRoutes: false,
        actionsForegroundColor: MyColors.mainColor,
      ),
      child: PostsTableList(category)
      );
  }
}

class PostsTableList extends StatefulWidget {

  final CategoryMetadata category;

  PostsTableList(this.category);

  @override
  PostsTableListState createState() => PostsTableListState(category: category);
}
```

and the state that build the list using a `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
class PostsTableListState extends State<PostsTableList> {
  final CategoryMetadata category;
  int _currentPaginationIndex = 1;
  final _apiPosts = APIPost.standard();

  PostsTableListState({this.category});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _getCall(_currentPaginationIndex),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<PostMetadata>> snapshot) =>
                _buildListWhenAvailable(context, snapshot)
          )
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListWhenAvailable(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<PostMetadata>> snapshot) {

    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.active: {
        return CupertinoActivityIndicator();
      } break;
      case ConnectionState.done: {
        if (snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data.length == 0) {
          return EmptyDataRefresh("No post available. Try to refresh",
          onRefresh: () {
            this.setState(() {});
          });
        } else {
          return ListView(children: _getListData(context, snapshot));
        }
      } break;
      case ConnectionState.none: {
        return EmptyDataRefresh("No post available. Try to refresh",
          onRefresh: () {
            this.setState(() {});
        });
      } break;
      case ConnectionState.waiting: {
        return CupertinoActivityIndicator();
      }
    }

    return Text("Errore sconosciuto. Provare di nuovo");

  }

  Future<List<PostMetadata>> _getCall(int paginationIndex) {
    if (category == null) {
      return _apiPosts.fetchPostMetadata(_currentPaginationIndex);
    } else {
      return _apiPosts.fetchPostsWithCategoryID(
          this.category.id); // For now this call doesn't support pagination
    }
  }

  List<Widget> _getListData(
      BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<PostMetadata>> snapshot) {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];

    for (var post in snapshot.data) {
      widgets.add(PostRow(post: post));
    }

    return widgets;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You should use streams**

When you press your refresh Button it should add to your sink.
And all the widgets subscribed to the stream will be refreshed.

I think you should learn more about streams. Try to learn **bloc pattern** it relies on the concept of stream.

Here is a link to get you started: https://medium.com/flutterpub/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1

Comment: Hi, it sounds interesting. If I get it right the streams are the Rx for Flutter and they allow to convert a stateful widget to a stateless one, moving the state management part to the Rx observable implementation?

Comment: I'm trying to implement the stream as you suggested but I don't get how this can sync the refresh button with the state of the list. Should I pass the `StreamController` from the navigation bar to the list and the button?

Comment: Rx is a library based on streams. You don't need rx library for streams. But rx makes life very simple

Comment: You should use Streambuilder widget. See docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html.

Comment: Did my answer helped you.

Comment: I have still to have a look in to it. Sorry 

Comment: Were you able to implement Streambuilder, should I add some code for example.

Comment: Ok, I tried to implement how you suggested (that involved lots of refactoring in the app that requested some time), but in the ends it still doesn't work as expected.
What I don't get is the logic: Even using Rx I should keep 2 references on the subscription. One on the Navigation Bar and One one the list status object?

Comment: Can you post your current code, how you have implemented

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [InheritedNotifier](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/InheritedNotifier-class.html) at your top-level widget, and the "refresh" button could update the value there, which would trigger a rebuild of every other widget that also accessed that value.